# Circumvent a proxy for a utility that uses libsoup (intel-linux-graphics-installer)

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, proxy

I am trying to use the [intel-linux-graphics-install](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7) package to get an older integrated graphics card working.  The installer utility cannot connect to the internet due to a proxy, and this [prevents it from continuing Failed installation the install process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeuMK.png).The console gives the following output, indicating that the program was indeed trying to download a file:

`Failed to download config file https://download.01.org/gfx/ilg-config.cfg`

While searching for the solution, I downloaded the source code of the installer and, after some investigation, discovered that it uses [libsoup](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupSession.html) to fetch config file.

So my question is this:  is it possible to pass the proxy settings to a utility so that the proxy settings access a resource online? I have the proxy credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume it's exactly the contrary and ILGI **isn't** using the proxy. Quite a few programs don't read the desktop's proxy settings and therefore don't work behind a proxy. I experience this every day in my school.

However, you can force such programs to connect through the proxy. For this, you have to start the program from a terminal, in which you set the proxy environment variables.

In your case, run the following commands in a terminal

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:1234
export https_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:1234
intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Replace proxy.example.com:1234 by the proxy address and port in your environment.

Attention: Even when using HTTPS, FTP, or any other protocol, you will most likely have to use the same protocol for the proxy (HTTP in the example above).

---

Site note for your own safety:

In the case of HTTPS, this means that your connection isn't private any more to a certain extent. Everything you do in the internet is routed through the proxy server, including the SSL handshake. So the proxy server (and with it its operators and people who illegally gain access to it) could at any time eavesdrop on your presumably safe connection.
So please don't do any E-Banking and other important things in a proxy environment where you can't trust the operator.

Comment: Using the `export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:1234` trick didn't work for me.  I figure that libsoup doesn't recognize those variables, and that there must be a way (similar to your suggestion) to get intel-linux-graphics-installer to use the proxy.

Comment: Did you replace "proxy.example.com:1234" by your proxy address and port? You also have to export https_proxy, as the address you're downloading from uses HTTPS.

Comment: Yep, I used the correct proxy address and port, and exported both the HTTPS and HTTP variables.

Answer (score 1):

Circumventing the proxy required a lot of source code changes. I have managed to get past that step by changing some other code.

1. I downloaded the ilg-config.cfg file manually from https://download.01.org/gfx/ilg-config.cfg
2. Copied the file into my home folder. (e.g. `/home/test/ilg-config.cfg`)
3. In `configuration.c` file, in the `get_configuration()` function, the line

   ```
   conffile = g_build_path ("/", g_get_home_dir (), ".ilg-config", NULL);
   ```

   creates the file named `/home/test/.ilg-config` which is wrong. I have changed the line as below:

   ```
   conffile = g_build_path ("/", g_get_home_dir (), "ilg-config.cfg", NULL);
   ```
4. Then, I commented out the if/else statement of

   ```
   http_download_file (CONFIG_URI, conffile, &error))
   ```

This helped me get the configuration file locally and move on to next step.